# Wait for a X window to appear/disappear (in a sane way)

Tags: bash, shell, python, window

Inside a shell script, I need to wait for a window that has a string on its title to appear, do some action, and then wait for it to disappear, and do some other action.

Until yesterday, I had this simple code. The problem with it is that the disk can't be put in a power saving state while the script is left running, and it can be for many hours:

```
while :; do
    until wmctrl -l | grep -q "$string"; do   # until
        sleep 0.5
    done
    : do action 1

    while wmctrl -l | grep -q "$string"; do   # while
        sleep 0.5
    done
    : do action 2
done
```

Since I decided the mentioned code was insanely waking the disk, I went through the documentation of a few command line tools, and decided on `xdotool` to wait for the window to appear, and `xprop` to figure out when the window has vanished:

```
while :; do
    # we use `until' because sometimes xdotool just crashes
    until xdotool search -sync -all -onlyvisible -pid $pid -name "$string"; do
        :
    done

    # xdotool isn't trustworthy either, so check again
    wmctrl -l | grep -q "$string" ||
        continue

    : do action 1

    xprop -spy -root _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING | while read line; do
        if [[ ! ${_line:-} || $_line = $line ]]; then
            _line=$line
            continue
        else
            _line=$line
            if wmctrl -l | grep -q "$string"; then
                continue
            else
                : do action 2
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
done
```

Now I have two new problems with the code above:

- `xdotool` not only crashes and gives strange results, as I have workarounded before, but it also sucks about 15% of CPU while left waiting for the window to appear. So that means I got rid of simple code that wakes the disk, to write code that is left wasting the CPU for hours, and my intention was saving power in the first place.
- `xprop -spy` will notify me every time I change focus (which I have workarounded through `$_line`) or create and destroy windows. That wakes the disk more frequently than xdotool.

I'm looking for a simple program that just waits for the window with the title `$string` to appear or disappear. It can be an existing command line tool, a python script, compilable C code..., but I should be able to integrate it somehow to my script (even if it just writes some information to a fifo)!

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to find out why your old code wakes the disk and search for a solution? Something like chroot and ramdisk. I guess `strace -f -e trace=file wmctrl -l` should be informative.

Comment: I'm using `fatrace` to check for disk wakeups, and it tells me `bash` reads `/bin/sleep` and `/usr/bin/wmctrl` every half second, that's why I'm looking for some program that'll actually wait for window events. Am I missing something?

Comment: reading those wouldn't wake up the disk as they would likely be cached if they were run twice every second. Did you mount your filesystems with noatime? See also `btrace` from `blktrace` to investigate sources of disk activity.

Comment: A better program may be the more elegant solution. But why should reading a cached file wake the disk? Why should reading `/usr/bin/wmctrl` wake the disk but reading `/what/ever/xdotool` not? I guess you have to look for write accesses (writes to files, creating files, deleting files). You should try a chroot to a ramdisk (which contains a bind mount of the X socket, of course).

Comment: @HaukeLaging, see also memlockd to lock some files in memory and avoid having to use a ramdisk (and a ramfs/tmpfs would probably be more appropriate than a ramdisk). `read` accesses can also cause writes because of the access time.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas they are mounted with noatime, so I guess the disk isn't really being waken, then.

Comment: I'll probably accept an answer teaching me how to measure if the disk is really being waken :) This memlock stuff is new to me!

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I meant "ramdisk" in the wide sense (tmpfs). Thanks for making that clear to the readers. Locking files into memory doesn't help here as this would not solve the problem of writing . I don't suggest tmpfs as a file cache but as chroot target.

Comment: If you haven't looked at it yet `xwininfo` might be of use, it certainly loads far fewer shared libraries than wmctrl and operates on a level closer to bare X.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas `btrace` fails on /dev/sda and /dev/sda1 with `25/Inappropriate ioctl for device`

Comment: @msw I'll have a look at the man page, thanks!

Comment: Oh, and sleeping for 0.5 seconds is better than no sleep, but not by much. What happens so urgently that you need that granularity of action? Is it possible to use some proxy item (a file) that tells you when the window is likely to change state? This question would be better if you explained what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @msw I'm trying to fix the unfixable, which is an autosave feature for Google Earth (closed sourced and reporting bugs is a waste of time)

Comment: @HaukeLaging could you explain a bit more about what I should try to achieve through a chroot to a ramdisk?

Comment: @TeresaeJunior See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you all (OK: most. What have I forgotten? Sockets?) file system activities which include writes:

```
strace -f command 2>&1 | 
  grep -e '^open.*O_CREAT' \
    -e ^write   \
    -e ^mkdir   \
    -e ^rmdir   \
    -e ^unlink  \
    -e ^rename  \
    -e ^chmod   \
    -e ^link    \
    -e ^symlink \
    -e ^mknod
```

With this information a working chroot environment can be created in tmpfs (as an action of last resort; maybe symlinks to tmpfs are enough). If the program is started in a RAM chroot then it does not have a chance to wake the disk directly. No write to its file system hierarchy is ever written to disk.

Comment: I believe there are times when reading a file, at least for the first time, will wake the disk too, isn't it? I'm wondering if `blktrace` would be the right tool for that, but it would require a kernel compilation `# CONFIG_BLK_DEV_IO_TRACE is not set` :( That is beyond the scope of this question, though. Thank you!

Comment: @TeresaeJunior Sure but who would consider that a problem? This is about keeping the script running all the time not about starting it. And you can create the tmpfs from `boot.local` / `rc.local` so that you don't have disk accesses even if you start the script later. I just had a look at `blktrace` (didn't know that before). That's so terrible I wonder if I will get to sleep tonight...

Comment: Yes, I shouldn't really worry about this one anymore, you're right again. But I think I'll also loose this night of sleep compiling the kernel, since I want to check everything that might be waking constantly the disk, not only this particular Google Earth hack :)

Answer (score 8):

It might be simpler, and more reliable, to rely on your window manager or X11 to handle this by writing a "real" X11 application.

What you want from the shell is something that registers with the window manager and waits for a desired event type before returning to the shell... it's much more load-friendly if you can avoid looping inside the shell.  (Your `until xdotool...` causes load because there's no delay (sleep) inside the loop.)

Ah... apparently `xdotool` had that feature added over year ago `--sync`.  That's not available in my current Linux distro (Debian Squeeze), so I haven't tried it out.

The xdotool developer answering a similar question to yours:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/xdotool-users/7zfKTtyWm0Q/DM6TSOBUWZMJ

Comment: Yes, exactly, `-sync` was supposed to do what I want, but it needs the `while` because it will eventually crash before the window appears, and wastes too much CPU. I actually compiled `xdotool` from source because the one from Debian was incredibly slow to type. Writing an application that interacts directly with X is actually beyond me. Thanks, though!